# Differences between stopPropagation() and stopImmediatePropagation() in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, events, apache-flex, flex4.5, stoppropagation

I am working on event handling in flex.
I need to stop event propagation of an event on a node.
I found no difference between `stopPropagation()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Is there any difference between these functions?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application     
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"     
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    initialize="init(event);">

    <s:layout> 
        <s:VerticalLayout/> 
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.Event;
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;         


            import mx.controls.Alert;

            public function init(e:Event):void {
                var object:Object
                p1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert);
                tw1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert);
                tw1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, showAlert);
                btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert);
                btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, showAlert);               
            }

            private function showAlert(e:Event):void {                              
                trace("stopPropagation !\n" + "Current Target: " + e.currentTarget + "\n"+ "Target: " + e.target + "\n" +"Type: " + e.type);
                //e.stopImmediatePropagation();             
                e.stopPropagation();                                
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    
    <s:Panel id="p1" title="Stops Propagation">
        <mx:TitleWindow id="tw1" 
                        width="300" 
                        height="100" 
                        showCloseButton="true" 
                        title="Title Window 1">
            <s:Button id="btn" label="Click Me"/>
            <s:TextArea id="ta1"/>
        </mx:TitleWindow>
    </s:Panel>  
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 4):

`event.stopImmediatePropagation()` - completely stops the event. No other listener will receive a call for that event.

`event.stopPropagation()` - prevents moving event to the next display list node but allow invoking listeners on the currentTarget object (if they exists).

See slightly modified your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    initialize="init(event);">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function init(e:Event):void {
                var object:Object
                p1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert);
                tw1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert);
                btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert);
            }

            private function showAlert(e:Event):void {
                trace("Event: " + e.type + "; Phase: " + e.eventPhase +"; Target: " + e.target.name + "; Current Target: " + e.currentTarget.name);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Panel id="p1" title="Stops Propagation">
        <mx:TitleWindow id="tw1"
                        showCloseButton="true"
                        title="Title Window 1">
            <s:Button id="btn" label="Click Me"/>
            <s:TextArea id="ta1"/>
        </mx:TitleWindow>
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

Output:

```
Event: mouseDown; Phase: 2; Target: btn; Current Target: btn
Event: mouseDown; Phase: 3; Target: btn; Current Target: TitleWindow14
Event: mouseDown; Phase: 3; Target: btn; Current Target: Panel5
```

First you receive the event on Button in Targeting phase (eventPhase=2) and then on TitleWindow and Panel in Bubbling phase (eventPhase=3).

If you modify event listener like:

```
private function showAlert(e:Event):void {
                trace("Event: " + e.type + "; Phase: " + e.eventPhase +"; Target: " + e.target.name + "; Current Target: " + e.currentTarget.name);
                trace("stopPropagation()");
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
```

Output:

```
Event: mouseDown; Phase: 2; Target: btn; Current Target: btn
stopPropagation()
```

Or:

```
private function showAlert(e:Event):void {
                trace("Event: " + e.type + "; Phase: " + e.eventPhase +"; Target: " + e.target.name + "; Current Target: " + e.currentTarget.name);
                trace("stopImmediatePropagation()"); 
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
```

You will get the same result:

```
Event: mouseDown; Phase: 2; Target: btn; Current Target: btn
stopImmediatePropagation()
```

It is because `stopPropagation()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()` are prevent event to go into the next phase (Bubbling).

To see difference between these methods you need to have **two event listeners** on the button 'btn':

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    initialize="init(event);">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function init(e:Event):void {
                var object:Object
                p1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert);
                tw1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert);
                btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert);
                btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showAlert2);
            }

            private function showAlert(e:Event):void {
                trace("showAlert(): Event: " + e.type + "; Phase: " + e.eventPhase +"; Target: " + e.target.name + "; Current Target: " + e.currentTarget.name);
                trace("showAlert(): stopPropagation()"); e.stopPropagation()                            // 1
                //trace("showAlert(): stopImmediatePropagation()"); e.stopImmediatePropagation();       // 2
            }

            private function showAlert2(e:Event):void {
                trace("showAlert2(): Event: " + e.type + "; Phase: " + e.eventPhase +"; Target: " + e.target.name + "; Current Target: " + e.currentTarget.name);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Panel id="p1" title="Stops Propagation">
        <mx:TitleWindow id="tw1"
                        showCloseButton="true"
                        title="Title Window 1">
            <s:Button id="btn" label="Click Me"/>
            <s:TextArea id="ta1"/>
        </mx:TitleWindow>
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

For `stopPropagation()` result is:

```
showAlert(): Event: mouseDown; Phase: 2; Target: btn; Current Target: btn
showAlert(): stopPropagation()
showAlert2(): Event: mouseDown; Phase: 2; Target: btn; Current Target: btn
```

For `stopImmediatePropagation()` result is:

```
showAlert(): Event: mouseDown; Phase: 2; Target: btn; Current Target: btn
showAlert(): stopImmediatePropagation()
```

As you can see `stopPropagation()` has **allowed** to receive `mouseDown` event for the second listener `showAlert2()`.

At the same time `stopImmediatePropagation()` has **prevented** a call of `showAlert2()`.